# WakefulBroadcastReceiver does not wake device from deep sleep

Tags: android

i set `AlarmManager` with method inside my WakefulBroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
public static final String WAKEUP = "wakeup";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Utils.PrintInfo("Alarm received!");

    try {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmWakefulService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, newIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context, long triggerAtMillis) {

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(WAKEUP, true);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pi);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pi);
}
}
```

and my `AlarmWakefulService`

```
public class AlarmWakefulService extends IntentService {
public AlarmWakefulService() {
    super("AlarmWakefulService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLockLauncher");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    Utils.PrintInfo("AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver, Completed service @ "
            + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiveActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("ALARM_TIME", intent.getStringExtra("ALARM_TIME"));
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(newIntent);

    wakeLock.release();
    wakeLock = null;

    AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
}
```

both are in Manifest file

`<receiver android:name="com.xxxx.alarm.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" ></receiver>`
`<service android:name="com.xxxx.alarm.AlarmWakefulService" />`

also i get permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

not always alarm wake device, sometimes i have to unlock the device to alarm call, i try also set it with `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` instead of `RTC_WAKEUP` (also when i change  `RTC_WAKEUP` to `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` i change way to calculate `triggerAtMillis`) but then was even worst, device did not wake even more frequently.

Is there any other way to wake device from deep sleep?

Answer (score -1):

Your receiver needs to be run on a remote process. This allows the system to wake that process. Use this in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="com.maxcom.alarm.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" />
```

I just added the `android:process=":remote"` declaration to the receiver.

Comment: after year i cant reproduce that error, thanks for answer next time i'm gonna try that

Comment: I didn't realize until after I answered that this was a year old. Someone else answered and that must have brought it to the front page